# Index Minif excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that looks for a value in column A, finds the smallest value of that row and displays the corresponding value of a row on the top of the sheet (row 3 in my case) where the smallest value has been found.
also would like to find the second and third smallest value and display the value of row 3.

For example: I need to lookup X in the first column, find the smallest value in that row (1) and display the value on the row on top of that column (D)
and second smallest value for X to display C, third smallest for X to display E.

```
enter code here

A   B    C   D    E     F

Z  6   8   9   5    2

X  7   2   1   3    7

Y  9   2   6   1    6
```

Answer (score 0):

This codes should work:

=INDEX($B$2:$F$2,MATCH(MIN(IF($B$1=$A$3:$A$5,$B$3:$F$5)),INDEX($B$3:$F$5,MATCH($B$1,$A$3:$A$5,0),),0))

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGJEi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data are in range `A1:F4` as shown below:

[image: Example]

[image: Solution]

You can use the following formula to find the 1st, 2nd and 3rd smallest value in the row starting "X". Put it in Cell `I2` and drag it down.

```
=SMALL(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,MATCH("X",$A$2:$A$4,0),),H2)
```

Then you can use the following formula to find the corresponding value in the row starting "Z":

```
=INDEX(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,MATCH("X",$A$2:$A$4,0)-1,),,MATCH(I2,INDEX($B$2:$F$4,MATCH("X",$A$2:$A$4,0),),0))
```

It is basic **INDEX+MATCH** approach. If you have problem understanding the solution, I suggest you to google some online tutorials on the use of **INDEX+MATCH**. **SMALL** function is used to find the nth smallest value as requested.

Cheers :)